# Why doesn't code like `"A %s", "B" % "C"` interpolate "C" into the first string?

Tags: python, string, datetime, formatting

Im wrtiting a script which saves the current date and time as a filename but I get an error stating "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" I am new to Python andmay of missed something obvious. Code below:

```
from subprocess import Popen
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()

today = str(today)

print today

f = open("%s.sql", "w" % (today))
x =  Popen(["mysqldump", "-u", "root", "-pucsdrv", "normalisationtion"], stdout = f)
x.wait()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're putting the string formatting in the wrong place; it needs to be right after the string that's being formatted:

```
f = open("%s.sql" % (today), "w")
```

It's legal to not pass any formatting arguments, like you did with `"%s.sql"`, but it's not legal to pass arguments but not the right amount (`"w" % (today)` passes one, but there's no string formatting in `"w"`, so you get an error that not all of the arguments were used)