# (Not all arguments converted during string formatting in python)

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7

I want to insert a variable into a MySQL query using python. How can I do this?

I am using python 2.7.

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("host","root","password","database" )

cursor = db.cursor()

model=Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v2 @ 2.60GHz

mode=("INSERT INTO machinedetails (ModelName) VALUES (%s)")

cursor.execute(mode,model)

data = cursor.fetchone()

print (data)

db.close()

-------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "System_Info.py", line 149, in <module>

 cursor.execute(mode,model)

 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187, in execute

query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])\

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: You're passing the `mode` directly to the `execute` method, whereas it expects an iterable of the arguments. Try `cursor.execute(mode, [model])`.

Comment: Multiple questions with the same name have already been posted. That is why the title had to be put in brackets. A similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053500/typeerror-not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089038/python-not-all-of-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting

Comment: your model is not valid... model = "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v2 @ 2.60GHz"

Comment: Why are you using raw SQL with Django anyway?

Comment: yes multiple question is posted but the problem in my question is different from others @NoelWidmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming data type for your `ModelName` column is `varchar`.
Take model as string.

`model = "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v2 @ 2.60GHz"`

Your query should be like

`mode= "INSERT INTO machinedetails (ModelName) VALUES (%s)"%(model)
 cursor.execute(mode)`

For multiple columns having data types as Integer and Varchar.

`Column1 Int
 Column2 Varchar
 query = "INSERT INTO machinedetails (Column1,Column2) VALUES (%s,%s)"%(value1, value2)`

value1 is Int and value2 is String.
Hope this solves your problem.
But I agree with comments you shouldn't be using raw SQL in production code.

Comment: i tried your answer,error has been gone but i am getting ( ) as a output

Comment: Have you checked on your SQL server for Data? And also try with `fetchall()` with `where` clause (assuming your DB has multiple rows) if data is there in your DB.

Comment: Hold on. I just saw you're running `fetchone()` on same cursor object. `fetchone()` or `fetchall()` fetches data from cursor. Run query `select top 1 * from machinedetails` from your cursor object. Then do `fetchone()` on your cursor.

Comment: @sachindubey Plz accept and up vote answer if it works for you. Cheers!! :)